# Check the modified time of #+RESULTS file before exporting, then evaluate the code blocks selectively to save time?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Is there any configuration or package, which can make Org-mode checks the modified time of all `#+RESULTS`' files before `export` (maybe auto add a `#+MODTIME` for comparing I guess), then decide if a code block needed to be re-evaluate?

An Org file with a lot of `gnuplot` code blocks makes exporting very, very time-consuming...

Comment: Consider using the [`:cache yes`](http://orgmode.org/manual/cache.html#cache) header argument to avoid needlessly repeating expensive computations. (Let me know if I should convert this into an answer.)

Comment: Do you think that adding a ":cache yes" entry to a block sufficient
for this use case?

Comment: @HowardAbrams: your post was more of a comment, so I moved it as such.

Comment: @Constantine Thanks, problem fixed! Why not convert your comment into answer?